# wordpress min-height doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, html, css, wordpress-theming

I have a WordPress site  `http://fa.tamidhco.ir/`.
the first time a page is loaded, a div with `caroufredsel_wrapper` class has an empty space at the bottom.
It seems that the height property changes with jQuery. what should I do so the height property will change with the content?

```
<div class="caroufredsel_wrapper" style="display: block; text-align: start; float: none; position: relative; top: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: auto; z-index: auto; width: 703px; height: 724px; margin: 0px; overflow: hidden; cursor: move;">
  <ul class="offer_thumb_ul" style="text-align: left; float: none; position: absolute; top: 0px; right: auto; bottom: auto; left: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 4921px; height: 724px;"><li class="offer_thumb_li id_1" style="width: 703px;">
    <div class="image_wrapper">
```

Comment: You should read this post before asking any more questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the actual height of the 'caroufredsel_wrapper' class by jQuery.

```
var heightofdiv = $( ".caroufredsel_wrapper" ).innerHeight();
```

Then you can apply the height via jQuery css.

```
$(".caroufredsel_wrapper").css("height", heightofdiv);
```